# PHP IF condition on results of SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, if-statement, pdo

I want to send a mail using PHP Mailer, but first I need to validate 3 tables

This is the code I have,

```
//First I query the 2 tables to validate today's data and 3rd table to see if mail already sent
$verifyJobData = $dbconnection->query("SELECT id FROM [Jobs] WHERE date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)");
$verifyJobData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$verifyWIPData = $dbconnection->query("SELECT id FROM [WIP] WHERE date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)");
$verifyWIPData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$verifyDuplicateMail = $dbconnection->query("SELECT status FROM [Mail_Log] WHERE mailtype = 'DailyStatus' AND datesent = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND status = 1;");
$mailStatus = $verifyDuplicateMail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$mailStatus=$mailStatus->status;
//On the first IF I want to validate that IF $mailStatus->status is different than 1 pass to the next IF to validate the other data
if ($mailStatus != 1) //Enter next IF
{ 
    if ($verifyJobData->rowCount() && $verifyWIPData->rowCount())//The select had result continue to send code
    {
        echo "Code to send mail already working";
    }
} else {
    echo "Do not send mail and execute Code to insert failure status to DB also working";
}
```

The first IF is not validating the $mailStatus IF the value is 0, null or different than 1 also passes to the next IF.

This is what I tried, I did a lot of research but I am not finding what I need I might be searching wrong, also if you can share the URL to read the examples

Comment: And what is your exact error?

Comment: Why not do a `SELECT COUNT` instead of making the DBMS build an unnecessary resultset only for you to ignore it and only look at the number of rows returned

Comment: `fetchAll` normally returns an array, so try `$mailStatus=$mailStatus[0]->status;`

Comment: Or do a simple debug `print_r($mailStatus);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was wrong using fetchAll , It worked with $mailStatus=$mailStatus[0]->status;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
switch($mailStatus){
    case 1:
        echo "Do not send mail and execute Code to insert failure status to DB also working";
        break;

    default:        
        if ($verifyJobData->rowCount() && $verifyWIPData->rowCount()) {
            echo "Code to send mail already working";
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you comment on how this would help with the OP's problem?